Switch loop light convert to ceiling fan
I am wanting to convert a ceiling light on a single pole switch that is switch looped to a ceiling fan light combo and have that controlled by the currently exiating single pole switch.. is this as easy as pig tailing a hot and neutral in the new fan box I installed, or is there a rewire in my future.. the wire for this light appears to come from an outlet, then goes to a single pole switch with a switch loop.. also,  off the light receptacle box there is another light ran down stream similarly wired.
Updated with photos.. thanks again for all the help. Let me know if the photos change any ones mind. Thanks!
Last edit:
Realized my wiring mistake with the white that goes from fan to switch is a "hot" .. got the fan installed and it works as advertised. Thanks for all the help!

Can you upload pictures of the existing wiring? Also, not clear - are you changing from a light to fan+light? If so, do you want to control light and fan separately? Does the new fan come with a wireless remote control?

Converting from a stand alone light fixture to a fan light combo.. only 1 switch to control both light and fan function is perfectly fine.. no wireless remote for the model I bought. But if that's a need to make this work, I can revisit, lol.. I'll try to attach a photo..  photo added sorry for poor quality, the top left wire goes down stream to a kitchen light, the top right feeds the power and the bottom wire goes to the switch. The switch has the black wire up top and the white on the bottom of the single pole switch...

Can we have photos of the insides of the boxes please?

The big question is the box in the ceiling. If it is not rated for a fan, it must be changed. First appearance is that it is not fan rated.

I did update to a ceiling fan box.. I just hadn't taken a photo afterwards from the attic

If you are fine with "the light and the fan are always and only on together" or "any independent switching of the fan and light are done at the fan" whether by a remote or by pull-chains, it should be (from a wiring point of view) a matter of connecting the fan the same way the light is connected (but if the fan has separate hots for fan and light, they will both join the single hot that feeds the light now.)
The other thing that may well be more trouble will be upgrading the box to one rated to hold a fan, if it is not that now, or you risk having a fan on the floor, possibly hitting you, your family members, or your pets on the way down and making a big mess.
If you want independent switching of light and fan NOT done at the fan, you'll need to rewire, and when rewiring you'll need to upgrade to current code for switch loops (so you'll need /4 cable to provide neutral, hot, and two switched hots at the switch location.)


only 1 switch to control both light and fan function is perfectly fine

That's what you've got now.  Yes, it will work.  If you decide to add separate switches then you would need to add a 3 + ground cable to the old work, from the fan to the switch box.  That would allow a total of 2 neutrals, 2 switched hot, and one unswitched hot wire.

I wasn't sure due to the switch loop on the light switc (see added photos), my last house had all the lights power run from the switch to the receptacle, so this one tripped me up a bit.
